# Is there a syntax for default-naming a unique-parameter lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda

I was wondering if there was a syntax in C# to not provide a parameter name for a 1-parameter lambda.

Like expressing this:

```
Func<A,B> = x => x.Stuff;
```

as

```
Func<A,B> = $.Stuff; // is there a syntax similar to that?
```

The goal is to simplify Linq expression:

```
enumerable.Where($.Date1 == $.Date2).Select($.Blah);
```

If this doesn't exist, is there a proposal to add this sort of things in a later version of the language? If not, is there a reason why this couldn't be added? I'm guessing that knowing where the function starts is a little tricky.

Comment: This doesn't exist, nor is it planned.  What problem does this really solve?  IMO, it's just making the lambda harder to read.

Comment: Aside from the suggested syntax, there are other approaches to simplifying LINQ expressions, such as method group conversion using well-defined methods: http://chevtek.io/how-to-simplify-complex-linq-expressions/

Answer (score -5):

No it doesn't exist. This is not a feature in C#.